# Pine Script. Heinkin Ashi Candles source

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I've been testing a strategy based on Heikin Ashi(HA) Candles, I tried three different sources of HA candles, one using code to do the math, and other two using the `security` function. All three had different results. I would like to know what is the most reliable one, and if anyone knows why the difference between them.

Follow the code:

1. From security

> ```
> Heikin Ashi from Security
> UseHAcandles    = input(true, title="Use Heikin Ashi Candles in Algo Calculations")
> hkClose = UseHAcandles ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid),
> timeframe.period, close) : close
> hkOpen  = UseHAcandles ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid),
> timeframe.period, open) : open
> hkHigh  = UseHAcandles ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid),
> timeframe.period, high) : high
> hkLow   = UseHAcandles ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid),
> timeframe.period, low) : low
> ```

2. From security

> [hkOpen, hkHigh, hkLow, hkClose] =
> request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid),
> timeframe.period, [open, high, low, close])

3. From math

> ```
> hkClose         = (open + high + low + close) / 4
> hkOpen          = (open[1] + close[1]) / 2     
> hkHigh          = math.max(high, math.max(hkOpen, hkClose))
> hkLow           = math.min(low,  math.min(hkOpen, hkClose))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable option is the "math" one I think
I like that one: https://www.tradingview.com/script/HtNYMuBO-Heikin-Ashi-Source-Function/